# Using a dependent project for test objects

Tags: java, maven, testing, dependencies, code-coverage

Assume that I have multiple java projects, all of them use maven: Project A and Project B

- **Project A** is a library
- **Project B** is an application which uses **Project A**

Both projects are developed simultaneously. New requirements from **Project A** are fulfilled with a new release of **Project B**.

I mostly tested my code manually which - as expected - yielded less than optimal code coverage and therefore quality.

I'm therefore currently looking into using Junit to write tests for my projects. Since **Project A** mostly defines interfaces, I would have to - at least I believe so - write implementations of these classes in the test code.

As I already have implementations of those interfaces defined in **Project B** I figured I could use **Project B** as `test` dependency in **Project A**, which at first glance would make perfect sense as nearly all features of **Project A** are used in those implementations, as I would (at least for now) not develop a feature in **Project A** that is not used in **Project B** (*Keep in mind: this might change for future projects e.g. **a newly created Project C**, which might also depend on **Project A***).

On the other hand this would create some sort of circular dependencies. In **Project B**'s `pom.xml` I would define a regular dependency on **Project A**, while **Project A** would have a dependency on **Project B** in the `test`-scope.

Therefore the following questions:

- Is this even technically possible or would I run into issues with the circular dependencies right from the start or at a later point in time? (I believe I've seen someone doing something similar, where they had to define the correct version of **Project A** in **Project A**'s `<dependencyManagement>` section to make sure the current code is used while testing and not the version defined in **Project B**. *I can't find it anymore though, so I can't verify this, but I remember being confused on why they would define their own projects version in that section*. **Edit:** I believe I found it again, but it seems to be something else, I was propably just kind of confused while researching junit and testing ;) )
- Is it desirable to use a downstream project for classes for a test case or are there issues I could face at a later point in time? (My first thought would be that I'd run into a problem as soon as I replace **Project A** with a third party dependency in **Project B**, therefore loosing all my test cases for **Project A**)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not a good idea.

First of all, you create circular dependencies. Secondly, you don't test what you want to test, namely project A (not project B).

So, what you gonna do instead?

Firstly, think whether it is really sensible to have two separate projects A and B if they are developed simultaneously. You could put them into a multi-module project instead.

Secondly, if A are mainly interfaces, it may be more sensible to test B (in integration with A), instead of A alone. If you find that there are things in A which are worth testing, you can use mocking (like mockito) to mock the interfaces that appear in your tests.

Comment: Just test the code that is in A with unit tests in A, and the code in B with unit test in B. What if you end up with project C which also implements interfaces from A? Obviously that will need a different test suite than the implementations B has, so the tests belong where the implementation lives, not where the interface lives.

Comment: Thank you for the response!

Maybe I should clarify I bit, as I'm not entirely sure if above fits my case:
Those interfaces use reflection (e.g. to serialize an object in a certain way). Just mocking the interface would/ should - as far as I understand - yield an empty serialization. 

Testing B in integration with A sounds like a good idea, but is there anyway to run these tests automatically from CI tools such as github actions? Tests in A would be run automatically in the build process of A, tests written in project B would not run in the build process of A.

Comment: Mocking can yield any kind of response, depending on the context. You can use JUnit tests that test B and A together. These would run in the build process of B.

Comment: Testing A and B together is propably not useful for me, as I'd like to know if the additions to my code broke anything as soon as I push to github. 

But I will take a deeper look into mocking for poject A. Thank you.

Comment: If these projects are tightly coupled, it may be better to manage them in one git repository as multi module project.

Comment: That would make perfect sense. Thank you. I can't do this personally though as those libraries were originally developed in a team for another project, which was put on hold for external reasons, but developement on those libraries continued, as I also depend on them with my private project B (which is the reasons why I can't put both in one repository) and as we intend to eventually continue the bigger project. Thank you anyways for the great input :) I will accept your answer as these arguments make perfect sense to me. For aforementioned reasons I will probably test each project seperetaly.